# Unable to find Airflow.cfg file

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have set up the Airflow environment on AWS EKS using the official doc
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html

The pods are up and running:
[image]

From pods description I can see that there is supposed to be a mount for airflow.cfg:
[image]

But when I try to check the path and mount on the node, I am unable to find the airflow.cfg file at /opt/airflow.

I am using 2.3.0 version currently, but the same was seen with 2.4.1 and 2.5.1 versions.
How is airflow running without airflow.cfg?

Let me know where can I find this file.